# How to clear space (%20) and remove the file extension (.htm) in web url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to remove spaces that generates %20 and .htm extensions in my web url (links) with .htaccess

I dont know how to write the rule for spaces but below is what I have for file extension and that is not working either. I am hosting with GoDaddy

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.htm [NC,L]
```

I have tried the above .htaccess rule but it is not working.

I want to change **mysite.com/blog/what-is-bubul.html** to **mysite.com/blog/what-is-bubul**

Also clear spaces that comes up as %20 from links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Loading file from extensionless request

You need to rephrase it in reverse.

When you access the link `mysite.com/blog/what-is-bubul`, it should return the file `mysite.com/blog/what-is-bubul.html`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

#### Redirect request if spaces found (replace there to `-`)

I have added the space removal code as well. In this case, the `.htaccess` file redirects the user from the `mysite.com/what%20is%20ubul` link to the `mysite.com/what-is-ubul` link.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^%20]*)%20([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/%1-%2 [L,NE,R=301]
```

#### Code with comments

```
# Run this code IF "mod_rewrite" module was enabled
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Enable server-side redirects
    RewriteEngine On

    # 1.) Remove spaces
    # 
    # %{THE_REQUEST}: url
    # ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^%20]*)%20([^\s]*): find charachters before and after spaces
    # [NC]: treats lowercase and uppercase letters equally
    # 
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^%20]*)%20([^\s]*) [NC]
    #
    # if find spaces in url, then redirect url without spaces
    # 
    # ^: insert it after domain
    # %1: before chars
    # %2: after chars
    # [L]: this will last rule, instructs the server to stop rewriting
    # [NE]: without escape, instructs the server to parse output without escaping characters
    # [R=301]: redirect an entire site via 301 permanent server response
    #
    RewriteRule ^/%1-%2 [L,NE,R=301]

    # 2.) Return content of html file
    # If exists file as REQUEST_FILENAME .html in server
    #
    # %{REQUEST_FILENAME}: part after domain (mydomain.com/test -> test)
    # %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html (mydomain.com/test -> test and .html -> test.html)
    # -f: check file is exists
    #
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    #
    # if true, will get content of this html
    # ex.: call mydomain.com/test and exists test.html, will get content of test.html
    #
    # [NC]: treats lowercase and uppercase letters equally
    # [L]: this will last rule, instructs the server to stop rewriting after the preceding directive is processed
    #
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

#### Code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Remove spaces
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^%20]*)%20([^\s]*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/%1-%2 [L,NE,R=301]

    # Return content of html file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

#### More instruction

###### Location of `.htaccess`

Place your `.htaccess` file in the folder of your website (alongside `index.php`/`index.html`, etc.)! You don't have to do anything to run this. You just need to put it in the right place, next to the file called by the web server!

###### Everything is OK, but...

If you have completed the steps, but it still doesn't work.

The server does not support the mod_rewrite module: The mod_rewrite module must be enabled on the server for Rewrite rules to work. If it's not enabled, then the Rewrite rules will not execute. Check the server settings or ask your hosting provider if they support this module.

Contact the server administrator and request technical assistance!

Comment: Thank you!, I found I needed to add Options +MultiViews For GoDaddy hosting too. It works